# Handling environment changes in a production rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment

I have worked on several rails projects but they have always been on one off projects that I've done by myself and only a few have I deployed to something like heroku and kept using regularly. I just started a project with a few other developers and I'm not completely familiar with this type of environment. In particular, handling changes to my local environment and keeping the other developers' environments in sync.

For example, I just added configuration for ActionMailer to use our sendgrid account and put the values as environment variables on my system. When one of the other developers pulls my changes from source control they won't have those environment variables. So, I have to manually send them something to tell them what to add.

The point of my question is, what is the norm for handling things like this? I would imagine something using rake? Is there a way to automate it so that when a pull is done the changes are made automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the configurations in your config file for different enviornments and use them in your environments.

//eg:

```
common: &common
  http_auth:
    username: 
    password:

 development
   <<: *common
 test:
  <<: *common

 staging:
  <<: *common

 production:
  <<: *common
```

These defined variables you can use in your application using AppConfig.http_auth["username"], AppConfig.http_auth["password"]

If your deploying to heroku you can specify ENV variables that can be set on heroku and accessed as follows:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings       = {
 :address        => smtp.sendgrid.net,
 :port           => ENV['SENDGRID_PORT'],
 :authentication => :plain,
 :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USER_NAME'],
 :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
 :domain         => AppConfig.preferred_host
}
```